# Extract table from html text

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to extract text from a page and save it as a dataframe. The page is not formatted as  tag and therefore pandas can not read it directly. I tried to use bs4 but not able to extract the exact URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/veryimp/claps-0001.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml") 


links = soup.find_all('li')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(links)
```

I expect dataframe of 4 columns, something like this...

```
vote title date url
1 How a TV Sitcom Triggered the Downfall of Western Civilization 2016-03-23 12:23 https://medium.com/p/how-a-tv-sitcom-triggered-the-downfall-of-western-civilization-336e8ccf7dd0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the html . `find_all('li')` just find all li in the hmtl you need to more spesific.

This is all code :

```
html = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/veryimp/claps-0001.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
import pandas as pd

links = soup.find_all('li')

all = []
for elements in links:
    find_a = elements.find('a')
    vote = find_a.previous_sibling
    vote =int(re.search(r'\d+', vote).group()) #remove the + and - Just get int
    title = find_a.text
    date = elements.find('time',attrs={'class' : 'dt-published'}).text
    url = find_a['href']
    all.append([vote,title,date,url])

dataf = pd.DataFrame(all,columns=['vote', 'title', 'date','url'])

print(dataf)
```

Answer (score 4):

`soup.find_all('li')` just returns all the `li` tags from the page. What you need to do is to get the relevant information from each `li` tag such as Votes, Title, Date and Url and then save this into perhaps a list of lists. Then you can convert this into a dataframe. You can get the url using BeautifulSoup by using the `'href'` attribute of `'a'` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
html = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/veryimp/claps-0001.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
links = soup.find_all('li')
final_list=[]
for li in links:
    votes=li.contents[0].split(' ')[0]
    title=li.find('a').text
    date=li.find('time').text
    url=li.find('a')['href']
    final_list.append([votes,title,date,url])
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list,columns=['Votes', 'title', 'Date','Url'])
print(df)
#just df if in Jupyter notebook
```

Sample output from Jupyter notebook

[image]